# Выскакивающее оповещение jquery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

пытаюсь написать код ,чтобы при нажатии на кнопку лайка товара сверху вылезало оповещение ,что товар добавлен или убран из избранного .Если нажимать на одну кнопку подряд,то все работает ,но если нажать подряд 2 кнопки из одинакового положения(лайкнуть подряд сколько-то или убрать из лайкнутого сколько-то),то ничего не высвечивается .Я предполагаю ,что проблема в том ,что если стиль уже применен ,то заново он не применится ,поэтому попытался удалять все классы оповещения при нажатии лайка ,но это не работает.Помогите пожалуйста ,уже 2 день не могу понять ,что нужно сделать.

```
$(".liked_check").click(function(){
  

  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.liked_alarm').removeClass('disliked');
      $('.liked_alarm').removeClass('liked');
      $('.liked_alarm').find('span').text("Добавлено в избранное");
      $('.liked_alarm').addClass('liked');
      
   } else {

    $('.liked_alarm').removeClass('liked');
    $('.liked_alarm').removeClass('disliked');
    $('.liked_alarm').find('span').text("Убрано из избранного");
    $('.liked_alarm').addClass('disliked');
    
   
   }
```

});

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пришлите пожалуйста разметку тоже, а лучше мини-пример со стилями. Из текста не совсем понятно что нудно исправить.

Comment: Или я могу сделать свой вариант, не трогая ваш исходный код.

Comment: @MaxWatson Вот,держите пример,если вы попробуете нажать 3 кнопки подряд по очереди,то заново анимация не будет проигрываться   https://jsfiddle.net/yhdf40q2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я ваc правильно понял, то вы добиваетесь такого результата. Если нет, расскажите детальнее о результате который хотите видеть в конце.

В моем примере, мы не будем выводить оповещение в `span`, мы будем создавать этот `span` с нужным нам текстом с помощью оператора `html`.

```js
$(".liked_check").click(function(){
      

if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.liked_alarm').html("<span id='liked_alarm_nadpis' class='liked'>Добавлено в избранное</span>");          
} else {
    $('.liked_alarm').html("<span id='liked_alarm_nadpis' class='disliked'>Убрано из избранного</span>"); 
  }
});
```

```css
.knopka{
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:black;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.checkbox{
  position:absolute;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  top:15px;
  right:15px;
}

.liked{
    animation-name: green_an;
    animation-duration: 4s;
  
}
.disliked{
    
    animation-name: red_an;
    animation-duration: 4s;
  
}

@keyframes green_an{ 
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    50% {background:green;
    opacity: 0.5;
    
    }
    100%{opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes red_an{
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    50% {background:red;
    opacity: 0.5;
    
    }
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.liked_alarm{height:30px;
width:100%;
opacity:1;
}

.block{
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:50px;
display:flex;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="liked_alarm"></div><!--Сюда помещает span их js -->
<div class="block">
   <div class="knopka">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liked_check"/>
   </div>
   <div class="knopka">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liked_check"/>
   </div>
   <div class="knopka">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liked_check"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!